# API Versioning when changing a single HTTP Method of an entity

Tags: design-patterns, rest, api-design

When making a decision to version an API. If you are making a change to an entity but are only making changes to the one of the HTTP Methods.
For example `POST /api/v1/customers` accepts a list of customers instead of only a single entity.

Should I grandfather the other endpoints to v2 or do separate the versions at the HTTP level?

#### Option 1

**Before:**

```
GET    /api/v1/customers
POST   /api/v1/customers

GET    /api/v1/customers/1234
PUT    /api/v1/customers/1234
DELETE /api/v1/customers/1234
```

**After:**

```
GET    /api/v1/customers <--- No Changes
POST   /api/v2/customers <--- Now accepts a list of customers

GET    /api/v1/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
PUT    /api/v1/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
DELETE /api/v1/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
```

#### Option 2

**Before:**

```
GET    /api/v1/customers
POST   /api/v1/customers

GET    /api/v1/customers/1234
PUT    /api/v1/customers/1234
DELETE /api/v1/customers/1234
```

**After:**

```
GET    /api/v2/customers <--- No Changes
POST   /api/v2/customers <--- Now accepts a list of customers

GET    /api/v2/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
PUT    /api/v2/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
DELETE /api/v2/customers/1234 <--- No Changes
```

Comment: How about `POST /api/v1/multi_customers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example POST /api/v1/customers accepts a list of customers instead of only a single entity.

There's no REST/HTTP rule that says that a resource is only allowed to handle one kind of message body in a POST request.

The web analog would be having multiple forms that share the same form.action value.  Again, that's a perfectly reasonable choice to make, it allows you to take advantage of [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) that you might not be able to otherwise.

So it's possible that your best choice is:

```
GET /api/v1/customers

POST /api/v1/customers
exactly-one-entity

POST /api/v1/customers
list-of-entities
```

Potential problem: if you are trying to use one of the open initiatives to *document* your API, you may find trying to define resource that take multiple different kinds of entities in POST requests more than a little bit challenging to document.

For example, OAS 3.0.3 allows you to specify different schema that might appear in the body of an operation, but it is still a single *operation*.

---

If, on the other hand, you want an api that is easier to document in standardized ways (which is a perfectly reasonable thing to want), your best choice is likely to be *extending* your existing api with a new operation; the POST method is probably the right one to use, so you would need a new path.  `POST /api/v2/customers` is a fine choice.

Because general purpose components are still going to be using HTTP's cache-invalidation semantics, you'll want to pair that operation up with `GET /api/v2/customers`, for the same reason as before -- successful POST requests will automatically invalidate previously cached representations (retrieved using GET) and meta data (retrieved using GET or HEAD).

Note that adding a new path, with its operations, does not necessarily mean you need to remove the old path.  Depending on your goals, it may make sense to leave the original path live, or perhaps instead to [decommission](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8594#section-1.4) the old API on a generous schedule that allows your clients to adjust.

Comment: I am using spring mvc and found this annotation: Simple and elegant
`@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
private List<Data> data;`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is another answer to this question somewhere. Basically you should just do v2 of your api.

When you compile it its version 2, the client is version 2 and all the end points are version 2.

Separate versions per endpoint is a nightmare to manage and at the end of the day it boils down to the name of a directory. There is no cost to making them all v2 and its easier for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the new endpoint is backwards compatible (accepts original input, and returns original result) then in practice you do not need to version this. However, if you would like to adopt a formal API versioning policy then [this de facto standard](https://semver.org/) is a fine place to start.